# Program exception when I run a program with TextIO

Tags: java

I wrote the following test program using Eclipse IDE

```
01 package Prog01Cal
02
03 import textio.TextIO;
04
05 public class Prog01CalcClas
06
07  public static void main(String[] args) {
08      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
09
10      // Variables Declaracion;
11      int var1;
12
13      // Read line
14      var1 = TextIO.getlnInt();
15
16      // Print line
17      System.out.print("This is a Test Program");
18      }
19
20 }
```

Case 1:

When I comment out line 14 and I run the program, a window popup with this message:

> Errors in workspace
>   Errors exist in required project(s):
>   Prog01Calc
>   Proceed with launch?

I responsed "Proceed"

And the program apparently run fine and print the line:

This is a Test Program

Case 2:

But when line 14 is not comment, the program got the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>   at textio.TextIO.getlnInt(TextIO.java:547)
>   at Prog01Calc.Prog01CalcClass.main(Prog01CalcClass.java:14)

And the test program do not print anything

Just to clarify the project window in eclipse contains the following:

> Prog01Calc
>   JRE System Library [jdk 14.0.1]
>   __src
>   ____Prog01Calc
>   ______Prog01CalcClass.java
>   ________Prog01CalcClass
>   __________mainString[] ) : void
>   __textio
>   ____TextIO.java

Can somebody help me with this exception error?
I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: You're not configuring your classpath correctly (the library can't be found) but none of the information you're sharing will allow telling you what's wrong. There are clearly some compile-time errors so your IDE must be complaining about it even before you run the code. Listen to your IDE and come back here if this is not enough.

Comment: It appears that the problem is not in Prog01CalcClas.java but in TextIO.java, you even got a line number on the stack trace TextIO.java:547 take a look at that line

Comment: You sure that's all you got for an error message? The next line in the log is probably going to give you a more precise indication of the problem. Post that line. Is it complaining about packages? Symbol not found? Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't pay attention to the file structure at first, I had assumed `textio` was added as a jar, but it seems like the source code is in a single class in your project. My guess is that you did not set `textio` as a source root, so Eclipse is not compiling it.  Move `textio` under `src` and it should work.